# Throughput going up and down Newrelic

Tags: python, newrelic

the rpm on my page were like 170rpm. Then I made some changes so I was down for like 10 min and then I restarted the web. Now the throughput goes up and down all the time and I dont know why. Is it normal? If not, whats going on? PD: sorry for my english

[gyazo](http://gyazo.com/73351a17af8f7dab3893f1e300f8385d)

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those situations where you really need to contact New Relic support directly. It is possible that something about the changes you made has caused the fluctuation, but it could just be normal as well. Specific account information, and possibly debug logs, will be required to determine what the actual issue might be. Please go here:

https://support.newrelic.com/home

And open a new ticket with support.

Kyle Elmblade
New Relic
Technical Support Engineer